# SQL How can I get the absolute function to work correctly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres and teaching myself SQL I have a table called Zips which contains thousands rows and it has 2 columns Latitudes and Longitudes . I have the following Coordinates (-122.406417,37.785834) and I am using a query to find the closest matching pair however something is wrong with my query as it is not yielding the correct output, This is my query

```
SELECT city,state,latitudes,longitudes, ABS(-122.406417-longitudes +
37.785834 - latitudes) as area FROM zips  ORDER BY area  limit 5
```

Now this is the output from that query

[image]
That is the wrong output as the Third Row should be the First Row for instance notice it is inside an Absolute function

**Third Row:** (-122.406417 - -122.418) = .011583 (37.7945-37.785834) = .008666 total = **.202490**

**First Row:** (-122.406417 - -122.523) = .116583 (37.9046-37.785834) = .008666 total = **.235349**

Obviously the Third Row San Francisco is lower than the first Row, how can I fix that ? I am new to SQL but do know that the Third row has the smallest difference . Any suggestions would be great and this is Postgres 9.6

Comment: You'll love to use PostGIS extension to work with geographic information. http://postgis.net/ Your problem is a very simple task using PostGIS as you can use ST_Distance function to get distances between points and apply spatial indexes to your table which will make spatial queries faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your arithmetic is incorrect:

```
area = ABS(-122.406417-longitudes + 37.785834 - latitudes)

Row 1:  area = ABS(-122.406417- (-122.523) + 37.785834 - 37.9046)
             = ABS(0.116583 + -0.118766)
             = ABS(-0.002183)
             = 0.002183
```

and similar for row 3, which is consistent with the results you get. What I *think* you want is

```
SELECT 
    city,
    state,
    latitudes,
    longitudes, 
    ABS(-122.406417-longitudes) + ABS(37.785834 - latitudes) as area 
  FROM zips  
  ORDER BY area  
  limit 5
```

or more accurately if you want to sort by *distance*:

```
SELECT 
    city,
    state,
    latitudes,
    longitudes, 
    SQRT(POWER(-122.406417-longitudes,2) + POWER(37.785834 - latitudes,2)) as area 
  FROM zips  
  ORDER BY area  
  limit 5
```

Comment: more accurately, but that formula would be correct if it were projected X,Y coordinates. That distance is in degrees, and you're assuming 1 latitude degree is the same that 1 longitude degree.

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what was needed